# ElasticSearch - Exclude hit with metadata

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using ES 6.6 and I'm doing a search for documents that are older than the current date. There are only 2 documents, but I get 3 items returned. The 2 existing documents and the third, are the settings and mappings. I only want to get the two documents.

I tried to add a filter with "exists", but then ES not return any document:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "products"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "happening_at": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I search only with the range, I receive the 2 correct documents, but with extra "hit" without document, only with settings and mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, Adrián.

You are firing a `_search` across `all` indices since you've not specified any index name. Please try `GET <your_index_name>/_search { ... request body ...}`.

Also, `"gte": "now"` will hardly return any records since it means date `greater than or equal to current date`. In your case, you want records `older` than current date. So you could use `lt:now` or better still `lt:now/d` since `now/d` is good in terms of performance and allows caching.

Try the below:

```
GET <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "products"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "happening_at": {
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. even if I put the index, it still doesn't work. when I remove "exists" filter the query works fine, but it returns the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You have to POST your query :). If you want make a get please dont forget the /.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html